# Создание автоматически новой старницы, когда регистрируеться пользователь

Tags: php, mysql

Создание автоматически новой страницы, когда регистрируеться пользователь
Как такое, создать и чтоб потом именно к этому пользователю можно было редактировать информацию.

Страница регистрации:

```
<?php

include("../database/db_conection.php");
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $user_name=$_POST['name'];
    $user_lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $user_email=$_POST['email'];
    $user_position=$_POST['position'];
    $user_country=$_POST['country'];
    $user_pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $user_copass=$_POST['copass'];
    $salt="h4T3hd9Fse";

    if($user_name=='')
    {
        //javascript use for input checking
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the name')</script>";
    exit();//this use if first is not work then other will not show
}

if($user_position=='')
{
    echo"<script>alert('Please enter the position')</script>";
    exit();
}

if($user_country=='')
{
    echo"<script>alert('Please enter the country')</script>";
    exit();
}

if($user_pass=='')
{
    echo"<script>alert('Please enter the password')</script>";
    exit();
}

if ($user_pass != $user_copass)
{
    echo"<script>alert('Error... Passwords do not match')</script>";
    exit();
}else{
    $user_pass=md5($salt.$user_pass);
    $user_copass=md5($salt.$user_copass);
}

if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo"<script>alert('Please enter the email')</script>";
    exit();
}
//here query check weather if user already registered so can't register again.
$check_email_query="select * from users WHERE user_email='$user_email'";
$run_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_email_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Email $user_email is already exist in our database, Please try another one!')</script>";
    exit();
}
//insert the user into the database.
$insert_user="insert into users (user_name,user_pass,user_email,user_lastname,user_position,user_country,user_copass) VALUE ('$user_name','$user_pass','$user_email','$user_lastname','$user_position','$user_country','$user_copass')";
if(mysqli_query($dbcon,$insert_user))
{
    echo"<script>window.open('../../index.php','_self')</script>";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: А при чем тут регистрация? Это нужно делать на той странице, на которой хотите редактировать информацию

Comment: Я думаю, нужно прочесть книгу по PHP и mysql

Comment: я хотел, чтоб на сервере создавался файл, с именем и фамилией человека, и этот файл был бы профилем человек. Как такое можно реализовать?